# Using Win32OLE library in Ruby to automate a custom built C# application

Tags: ruby, win32ole

I have designed a custom Windows application in C#. Now, I would like to automate it using Win32OLE library in Ruby. I have absolutely no experience in using Win32OLE, so I would like to know when I create a new Win32OLE object using:

```
customApp= WIN32OLE.new('MyApp.Application')
```

it gives an error since it returns a null Win32OLE object.

Do I need to have a COM file for my application? If so, why is it needed? Also, could someone point me to all the files required by my custom application before I start trying to automate it using Win32OLE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly do you want to automate? If its by simple actions (tab,enter,etc. mimic the keyboard plus waits for some windows actions) you can use AutoIt.

http://codesnippets.joyent.com/posts/show/829

Everything starts with:

```
require "win32ole"
au3 = WIN32OLE.new("AutoItX3.Control")
```

It comes as a requirement of the rubygem watir. But you can see if there a more simple way to install autoit (its a .dll) for your ruby needs.

Comment: Well I want to automate a desktop application. I guess watir framework is useful for automating Web pages. I need to mimic keyboard as well as mouse-clicks and capture the data and look for a particular pattern.

Comment: Yeap, Watir its for automating WebPages, but it comes with AutoIt that will help to your needs.